# How to turn seconds (of one day) into text?

Tags: javascript, math

I have made this formula to turn a time as string into seconds (as integer)
`seperated = new Date().split(":");

seconds = seperated[0] * 60 * 60 + seperated[1] * 60 + seperated[2];`

How can I do this the reverse way?
I'm not very good at mathematics :)

EDIT:
I tried this: (the function makeTime(...) works)

```
function makeTime(timestr) {
var seperated = timestr.split(":");
return seperated[0] * 60 * 60 + seperated[1] * 60 + seperated[2];
}

function timeStr(integ) {
var hours = integ / 3600;
var minutes = (integ % 3600) / 60;
var seconds = integ % 60;
return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Comment: The opposite of multiplication is division

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/), and write a code some thing like follows

```
(new Date).clearTime()   
        .addSeconds(15457) 
        .toString('H:mm:ss');
```

EDIT:

Or

```
hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
totalSeconds %= 3600; 
minutes = totalSeconds / 60; 
seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming time is the number of seconds as an integer:

```
hours = Math.floor(time/3600)
minutes = Math.floor((time % 3600) / 60)
seconds = time % 60
timeString = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
```